# Why is Spring Data unable to detect the IsNewStrategy for MongoDB auditing?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

I am trying to enable Spring Data MongoDB auditing. But whenever I am trying to bring up my server I am getting below error. Could you please let me know what is wrong here? I am using Spring 4.1.6 and Spring Data MongoDB 1.7.0.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported entity
 com.idearealty.product.shopchat.persistence.model.IdeaRealtyUser!
 Could not determine IsNewStrategy.    at
 org.springframework.data.support.IsNewStrategyFactorySupport.getIsNewStrategy(IsNewStrategyFactorySupport.java:48)
   at
 org.springframework.data.auditing.IsNewAwareAuditingHandler.markAudited(IsNewAwareAuditingHandler.java:80)
   at
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AuditingEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AuditingEventListener.java:54)
   at
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AuditingEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AuditingEventListener.java:31)
   at
 org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
   at
 org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
   at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
   at
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.maybeEmitEvent(MongoTemplate.java:1609)
   at
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:792)
   at
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:742)
   at
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:76)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
 org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:434)
   at
 org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:419)
   at
 org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:391)
   at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
   at
 org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.save(Unknown Source)  at
 com.idearealty.product.shopchat.config.SetupDataLoader.onApplicationEvent(SetupDataLoader.java:52)
   at
 com.idearealty.product.shopchat.config.SetupDataLoader.onApplicationEvent(SetupDataLoader.java:1)
   at
 org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
```

Below is the entity code

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.TypeAlias;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

/**
 * @author Debopam
 *
 */
@Document(collection="IdeaRealtyUser")
@TypeAlias("user")
public class IdeaRealtyUser extends User implements UserDetails,Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String role;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Address address;
    //private String password;
    @Transient
    private String matchingPassword;

    @CreatedDate
    protected Date createDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    protected Date lastModifiedDate;
    @CreatedBy
    protected String createdBy;
    @LastModifiedBy
    protected String lastModifiedBy;
 //getter and setter
}
```

And configuration

```
<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    </bean>
    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017">
       <mongo:options connections-per-host="8"
                   threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="4"
                   connect-timeout="1000"
                   max-wait-time="1500"
                   auto-connect-retry="true"
                   socket-keep-alive="true"
                   socket-timeout="1500"
                   slave-ok="true"
                   write-number="1"
                   write-timeout="0"
                   write-fsync="true"/>
    </mongo:mongo>
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="shopchatdb" mongo-ref="mongo"/>
    <!--  
    <mongo:auditing mapping-context-ref="customMappingContext" auditor-aware-ref="com.idearealty.product.util.MongoAuditAware"/>
    -->
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="mongo"/>
    </bean>

    <mongo:auditing auditor-aware-ref="ideaRealtyAudit"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.idearealty.product.shopchat" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with how Spring determines base packages for entities or models. Overriding getMappingBasePackage() method resolves the issue. Below is the Spring Mongodb configuration file

```
@Configuration
//@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence.properties" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages={ "com.idearealty.product.persistence.model" })
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.idearealty.product.repository.mongodb")
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class PersistenceMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public PersistenceMongoConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean(name="mongoAudit")
    public AuditorAware<String> mongoAuditProvider() {
        return new MongoAuditAware();
    }


    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "shopdb";
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017),mongoClientOptions());
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions() {
        // override to more reasonable connection timeout (default is 10 seconds)
        return MongoClientOptions.builder().connectTimeout(1500)
                .connectionsPerHost(8)
                .maxWaitTime(1500)
                .socketKeepAlive(true)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.product.persistence.model";
    }

}
```

Comment: How do I give mappingbasepackage if i configure without extending AbstractMongoConfig

Answer (score -1):

To resolve the error, declare a `<mongo:mapping-converter />` and configure the `base-package` attribute to point to the package that contains your domain class. Make sure you use the `MongoTemplate` constructor that takes a `MongoDbFactory` and a `MongoConverter` and wire the corresponding bean definitions.

Besides that, you're configuration looks suspiciously broken. You declare two beans that result in a `Mongo` instance (one through the factory, one through the namespace). Also, it's recommended to rather use a `MongoClient` instance these days.

The most simplified config reduced to the bare minimum should look like this:

```
<!-- put options here -->
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongo" … />

<mongo:db-factory id="db-factory" mongo-ref="mongo" />

<!-- put your domain package here -->
<mongo:mapping-converter id="converter" base-package="…" />

<bean class="….MongoTemplate">
   <constructor-arg ref="db-factory" />
   <constructor-arg ref="converter" />
</bean>

<mongo:auditing …/>
```

Comment: Now I am getting below error class   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converter.mongoMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false , "numIndexesBefore" : 2 , "errmsg" : "exception: Index with pattern: { _fts: \"text\", _ftsx: 1 } already exists with different options" , "code" : 85 , "ok" : 0.0}

Comment: I fixed that but still I am getting the original error. Moving to Spring data 1.6.2 solved the issue. What am I missing?

Comment: The correct setup. I unfortunately cannot look into all the details of your project setup but what I posted is essentially what you need to do. The error you get is unrelated to the original problem and caused by indexing issues.

Comment: As I mentioned I fixed that indexing issue but still I am getting the original error for isNewStrategy.